# perl one liner for the normal string operation (not on File!)

Tags: regex, perl, bash, shell

Is there an perl/ sed one line operation for processing the $string inside a Shell script, but not the file operation ? The google results show that perl oneliners are only for file wise operation.

Forexample, inside my shell script, I use

```
$mycurrent_path="/cygdrive/c/project_1/sources/"
if[[ $1 == "/^project_\d$/i" ]]   # For example I call this shell script with "Project_7" as the arg
  perl -e -i 's/project_\d/$1/ $mycurrent_path`
fi
  echo $mycurrent_path
```

this should print smartly:
$
/cygdrive/c/project_7/sources/

perl is very flexible with reg exp but some how, with the try of above code, the perl dosen't act on the $mycurrent_path variable, (also im not sure if the reg expression " if[[ $1 == "/^project_\d$/i" ]]" works fine like I do in perl, lets assume this condition check passes somehow (by forcing with 1)and goes inside.

Answer (score 1):

```
$mycurrent_path="/cygdrive/c/project_1/sources/"

if[[ $1 == "/^project_\d$/i" ]]   # For example I call this shell script with "Project_7" as the arg
  mycurrent_path=`perl -pe "s/project_\d/$1/" <<<"$mycurrent_path"`
fi

echo "$mycurrent_path"
```

It is not good practice place shell variable (`$1`) directly in any script even it is protected by condition in `if`. Using bash parameter expansion should be far safer

```
$mycurrent_path="/cygdrive/c/project_1/sources/"

if[[ $1 == "/^project_\d$/i" ]]   # For example I call this shell script with "Project_7" as the arg
  mycurrent_path="${mycurrent_path/project_?/$1}"
fi

echo "$mycurrent_path"
```

Or safer perl version:

```
$mycurrent_path="/cygdrive/c/project_1/sources/"

if[[ $1 == "/^project_\d$/i" ]]   # For example I call this shell script with "Project_7" as the arg
  mycurrent_path=`perl -pe 'BEGIN{$s=shift}s/project_\d/$s/' "$1" <<<"$mycurrent_path"`
fi

echo "$mycurrent_path"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use bash without perl? Something like (Untested)

```
mycurrent_path=${mycurrent_path//project_[0-9]/$1}
```

perhaps you'll also need 'shopt -s nocasematch'...